# Steps in developing your own File system in Solaris 10

Tags: filesystems, solaris-10

I need to gather the steps I should ensure before writing own file system in Solaris. I have gone through several links for developing the file system in Linux which was quiet easy. But I could not find any related link in Solaris 10. May I get any help in that?

Comment: Some other recommendations: Develop on Solaris 11 rather than 10 because the dev environment is much easier to [get going](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72882/solaris-development-host). Don't think you even need to backport, same code for v10 and v11. Develop on X86 platform rather than SPARC (because then you don't need hw, but can do the dev inside VirtualBox). You won't need separate source code for X86 vs SPARC if you do it right.

Comment: Ok. As of now, I am looking for the steps for the development of file system either Solaris 10 or Solaris 11 ( as of now, I am not considering platform whether it is SPARC or x86).

Comment: You can start by reading here:  http://www.solarisinternals.com/si/sample/solaris_internals_ch14_file_system_framework.pdf  The OpenSolaris kernel source for open-sourced Solaris file systems can be found at http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/fs/

Comment: Thanks for the links provided. I had already gone through provided links. I also book "Solaris Internals". That looks insufficient. The descriptions of the VFS and Vnode functions are just one liners. I think that wont be much helpful to me. 

I was looking like a tutorial kind of thing. I am aware about the closeness of the source code of Solaris. Still looking what can help me in this.

Comment: After carefully looking into tmpfs code, I got to know the steps to write the file system on my own in Solaris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into tmpfs code in illumos project, I got following ideas to write the file system. I had to write memory based file system like tmpfs, procfs, etc.

Steps:

1) Create a vfs switch table. Provide the required mount options, flags, fs initialization function, etc for your file system in switch table object.

2) In file system initialization function, register the VFS and Vnode operations.

3) Handle the registed VFS and Vnode functions.

P.S. - This is very short story told above. You can look into tmpfs to write file systems in details.